# How to Programmatically add javascript dynamically from a custom module to modify a popup calendar property

Tags: 7, javascript

I need to add a JavaScript code to my custom module, to modify the property in a date popup calendar and make it dynamic.

According to the documentation of the date popup calendar, the syntax for modifying the MaxDate is:

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({
  maxDate: "+1m"
});
```

I have to write "+1m" dynamically because it may be "+2m", "+3m", etc, it is variable.

How can I write a JavaScript code in my custom module and effect the popup calendar? I am wondering if I use script tag and put the JavaScript code inside it.
In case, how can I do it by js?

Answer (score 1):

You can attach a script to a form using the form's #attached attribute. You can do this in hook_form_alter as follows:

```
function hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)
{
  if($form_id == 'targeted_form')
  {
    $form['#attached']['js'][] = array
    (
      'type' => 'file',
      'data' => drupal_get_path('module', 'my_module') . '/scripts.js',
    );
  }
}
```

If you need to pass values from PHP to the form, you can attach values using Drupal.settings:

```
function hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)
{
  if($form_id == 'targeted_form')
  {
    $form['#attached']['js'][] = array
    (
      'type' => 'setting',
      'data' => array('myModule' => array('someSetting' => 'some value')),
    );
  }
}
```

Now the value will be available in your form at:

```
Drupal.settings.myModule.someSetting
```

Combine these two techniques to attach a form and pass it some settings.